# Antlr4 lexer rule should only match if at the beginning of line

Tags: javascript, c#, antlr4

I am using Antlr4 with JavaScript and C#. I have a rule which should match only if it is at the start of line. If a expression starts with **REM** it should be recognized as comment and therefore be hidden. Otherwise it is not a comment.

- REM 1+1 is a comment
- 1+1 REM 2 is not a comment

The bellow code in my Lexer is the best I could do till now. But the problem is it works only if a have a new line before which is actually not that good.

```
START_COMMENT   : ('\r\n' | '\n' | '\f') ([R][E][M] | [;] | [@][ ]) ~[\r\n]* -> channel(HIDDEN);
```

I am interested to know if there is some kind of trick to tell the Lexer that a rule should only match if it is at the beginning of the line and nowhere else ?

Answer (score 2):

You could use a [predicate](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/predicates.md) that tests if the current character index of the lexer is 0 (indicating the start of a line). The disadvantage of this is that you add target specific code to your grammar. For JavaScript, this should work:

```
REMARK
 : {this.getCharIndex() === 0}? ( R E M | ';' | '@ ' ) ~[\r\n]*
 ;

framgment R : [rR];
framgment E : [eE];
framgment M : [mM];
```

Comment: Beside JavaScript I am using it also with C#. Is it possible to implement this for both languages ?

Comment: No, alas, inside the grammar, you embed a single language.

Answer (score 1):

this is probably a hacky way to do it, but when I had this problem, I simply told it to look for a new line before it, and then in my code, I checked if the inputted string is supposed to start with it, and in that case, I added a new line to the top. So I basically did this

```
comment: NEWLINE '//';
NEWLINE: [\r\n] -> skip;
```

then in my code:

```java
if (content.startsWith("//")) {
    content = "\n" + content;
}
```

Of course this has the disadvantage of any errors being one line off, but it may work in your case.